Setting up Test Resources Folder in Eclipse
Is there any way to setup and mark a package as Test resources package/folder in Eclipse IDE for java project for Junit5 which can be easily done in IntelliJ IDE ?.
Thanks.
I tried exploring ways like creating a package but failed to mark it as a test resource package.

Right-click the folder and choose Build Path > Use as Source Folder.

As soon as I toggle it, the apply and close button greys out. The only option available is cancel which upon clicking doesn't mark it as test resource.

There is no close button in the right-click menu.

Open the Java Build Path property page for the project, and expand the source folder's node on the Source tab. The last option is for whether it is for tests or not; double-click on the Yes/No value to toggle it.


As soon as I toggle it, the apply and close button greys out. The only option available is cancel which upon clicking doesn't mark it as test resource.

Maybe you need to edit the question and add your own screenshot.
